# SQL: Update every entry with value from another entry that share same column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, subquery

I have the following table trn_ReceiptLog

[image]

I am wondering if it's possible to update amount of entry #1 to have same as entry #2 IF amount of entry #1 is 0?

I have over 5000 of these entries that need to be updated, basically something like:

```
UPDATE trn_ReceiptLog SET amount = (SELECT amount FROM trn_ReceiptLog WHERE receipt_type = 0) WHERE amount = 0
```

But I am not sure how to do it for all entries individually, do I need some sort of loop?

Condition 1: Receipt type will always be 0 of the one where amount needs to be taken from.

Condition 2: person_id will always be identical across two of these.

Condition 3 (Optional): Only perform this update IF there is only one receipt_type = 9 (Sometimes there might be 3 or 4 entries with same person_id and being receipt_type 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions to calculate the information needed for the conditions.  Then the logic is simple:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             max(case when receipt_type = 9 then amount else 0 end) over (partition by person_id) as amount_9,
             sum(case when receipt_type = 9 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by person_id) as num_9s
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set amount = amount_9
    where receipt_type = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

With a self join:

```
update t
set t.amount = tt.amount
from trn_ReceiptLog t inner join trn_ReceiptLog tt
on tt.person_id = t.person_id
where t.receipt_type = 9 and tt.receipt_type = 0 and t.amount = 0
and not exists (
  select 1 from trn_ReceiptLog
  where entry_id <> t.entry_id and person_id = t.person_id and receipt_type = 9
)
```

The last part of the `WHERE` clause with `AND NOT EXISTS...` is the 3d optional condition.
See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1b477ec949507f1ad5355c3af1f26cf5).